# App Engine Domain CNAME Record - "ghs.google.com" or "ghs.google.com."

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, cname

I'm not too experienced with DNS records and I'm trying to point a www subdomain to Google App Engine via the registrar gandi.net.

When updating the CNAME record to direct traffic to ghs.google.com, is it critical that there be a period at the end of ghs.google.com in the zone file?

Currently the raw zone file line looks like this:

```
www 3600 IN CNAME ghs.google.com.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, you need to have the trailing dot.

You enter the entire hostname followed by a period when the hostname is not inside your domain.  Since google is outside your domain, you need the "extra" dot.

For example (using `example.com` as our domain), with the trailing dot, the CNAME would redirect to `ghs.google.com`.  Without the trailing dot, we'd end up at`ghs.google.com.example.com`, which isn't what you want.

Comment: Thanks, exactly the explanation I was looking for.

Comment: Most DNS admin tools add the tailing DOT by themselves nowadays. Nevertheless it is a good habit to write it. It's like the preceding slash in /file/paths/and/names